# Accessing the number of caller when a call got missed in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I m trying to take the recently missed call number from the call log. i used the below code i want to make it run in back ground, now i wrote this as a method in my mainActivity class, when a call moves to missed call log this function should work. how to make it possible plz help

```
  public void SendSMStoMissedCall()
{
    String[] strFields = {android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, 
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE, 
            android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE};

    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";

    Cursor mCallCursor = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,strFields, null, null, strOrder);

    if (mCallCursor.moveToFirst())
    {

        do 
        {
            boolean missed = mCallCursor.getInt(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)) == CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE;

            if (missed) 
            {
                String name = mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                number = mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER));
                String time = mCallCursor.getString(mCallCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE));
                      Log.d("PhoneLog", "You have a missed call from " + name + " on " + number  + " at " + time);  
                String ContactName = objUtility.getContactNameFromNumber(number);

                SendMessage(number);
                getCurrentLocation();
            }
       } 
      while (mCallCursor.moveToNext());

     }

}
```

Comment: so what doesn't work? which part of your code you expect to work but doesn't?

Comment: @Calvin i want to make this work in background, when a new missed call comes i want to get the number

Comment: I means which part doesn't work? You get a null cursor? or cursor is empty? or cursor return you wrong value? I can't help if I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @Calvin this will work, i just want to make it work like a service. can i implement 'phonestatelistener'?

Answer (score 0):

Create a service, implement a `PhoneStateListener` in the service. In the extended class of the `PhoneStateListener`, in the `onCallStateChanged` method put your code above in the `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` case.